# Including Java .jar into RobotFramework

Tags: java, jar, robotframework

I am new at testing.
I have a jar-file. There are two classes. First class A which has method f(), second has class Main where I have main method and in this method I create the instanse of A and can use method f. I want to write test for this method, but I don't know how to use this method in RobotFramework. I want to make it with command line, without plugins. Can you advice something?
P.S Also I have Test.robot

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] for the programming problem you're facing?

Comment: Thank you. I could solve it myself. The solution was in correct classpath and correct Library

Comment: For the interest of others would you be able to share what worked for you in more detail as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'll try to explain.
As example of my case. I have .jar where in package "my.package" I have class A with public method '

```
public String f(String name){
       return ("Hello " + name);
}
```

'
And with robotframework I need to make simple test. 
There was question: How to use method in this framework.
1. I need to write in

```
*** Settings ***
Library    my.package.A
```

2. After it the "f" becomes key word and we can use it in
   `*** Test Cases ***` as `f      John`
3. We need to write our .jar in class path as
   '`java -cp C:\.....\test-method.jar`'
4. Execute test.robot file.
   P/S
   Sorry for my English